# How can I decrease the height of cell?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to decrease the height of the table cells by using the following CSS, but it is not working.

```
.table tr>td.vert-align{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaebec;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<td class="vert-align">
  {% if post.url %}
  <h4><a href="{{ post.url }}" style="margin-left: 15px;"> <img src="{{post.image}}" height="70" width="70"/>
{{ post.title }}</a><span style="margin-left: 15px;" class="domain">
({{ post.domain }})</span></h4>
{% else %}
  <h4><a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" style="margin-left: 15px;">{{ post.title }}</a><span style="margin-left: 15px; "class="domain">({{ post.domain }})</span></h4>
{% endif %}
  <ol class="post-info">
    <div class="btn-group btn-breadcrumb">
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{ post.moderator.username }</span>
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{ post.pub_date | date }}</span>
      <span class="btn btn-default">{{post.views}}</span>
      <a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="btn btn-default">discuss</a>
      <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-default">{{post.category}}</a>
   </div>
  </ol>
</td>
```

I'm trying to display title/image/domain name in one line that fits nicely to the table, but right now height of the table is too long it just looks odd. I tried height:5px but it won't work

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Comment: you're targeting it wrong.. if you target the height of your table. You should be do like `.table{ height: 10px;}` .. Currently `.table tr>td.vert-align{` mean any column that has vertical align class will have a 5px height

Comment: What is the height of your TD now?  Looks like the content in the TD is forcing a height change.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña, I'm sorry I should've been more clear. I meant to decrease the height of cells in the table. if you see here, http://imgur.com/PLCbq7P the line divides the space right?I'm using table to do that and I want that cell height to be decreased

Comment: @Lowkase, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I see no use of a table in your code, but the problem might be caused by you having a ".table" selector instead of a "table" selector.
Dot means classname, no dot means html tag. Please give it a look and if this is not the answer post your whole html code to get a better look at it.

Comment: I put .table because I have <table class="table">, I've tried table{} and .vert-align but none of them works

Comment: I see. Can you post the entire HTML then? Or at least the full table

Comment: I'm sorry I should've been more clear. I meant to decrease the height of cells in the table. if you see here, imgur.com/PLCbq7P the line divides the space right?I'm using table to do that and I want that cell height to be decreased

Comment: my whole table is ginormous I'll post it on fiddle

Comment: I'm not sure where to post my whole table, so I posted here https://www.reddit.com/r/html5/comments/40k132/my_html_code/

Answer (score 0):

You have already class for your `td`, so directly use it in your selector.

```
.vert-align{
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaebec;
}
```

**Update:**

Decrease the height of your image which is inside the `td` to decrease the height of cell.

Comment: this doesn't work either, this is where I'm at: trying to decrease the height of cells in the table. if you see here, imgur.com/PLCbq7P the line divides the space right?I'm using table to do that and I want that cell height to be decreased

Comment: Is there a way to decrease the height of cell without changing the size of image? is this because I declared the style for image inside html?

Comment: thanks for the fiddle,if I delete the defined style and use css...the image becomes enormous....I must've defined css wrong. and changing the height of the image doesn't change the height of cell as well...

Comment: if I define the style of image in css right, the height of cell should be decreased?

Comment: @lip123809 yes, the height will decrease and then you can control the height of the cell through the CSS code you defined.

Comment: hmmm... I don't want to change the size of the image tho. it's already small but the height of cell is just too big. if you see http://imgur.com/PLCbq7P, there's so much empty space between cells. just want to delete them